# How to use Luis.ai Auth Settings

Tags: oauth, active-directory, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

Can anyone provide a URL or tutorial to the help with setting up the Auth Settings tab in Luis.ai?  I am building a tool that allows anyone without coding experience to create a Chat Bot exclusively based on Luis.ai and it's Cognitive Services API.  I could ask users to provide their app id and subscription id; but I would rather have an Oauth login so they wouldn't have to share those keys with my service.

I asked Microsoft through there support over a week ago, and no response. I am just trying to understand if Oauth configuration is possible and how?    Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Spoke with Microsoft and currently the ability to Share the service without divulging the subscription key is not available; however if you visit this Microsoft URL and vote for the feature, they will consider it.

https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/551524-luis/suggestions/15365835-sharing-luis-applications

It is currently under review for implementation.